# Show statistics for ssh connection

Tags: ssh, connection, timeout

I am suffering since a long time an ssh timeout with one of my hosts. I have tried several things, including changing `ClientAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveInterval`, but I do not get it to work.

I would like to debug the problem in detail. Is it possible to tell the ssh client to report statistics about the internal counters? Things like "keepalive messages sent", "unanswered keepalive messages" and so on. Any kind of internal counters would be helpful.

Is it possible to dump this information from the running ssh client? I have not been able to find that in the man page.

Comment: You could try running a second sshd instance in debug mode on a separate port to see if it gives you anything helpful.

Comment: @Jenny D: Thanks, looks like a good idea! I'll try that. Anyway, if somebody knows about counters, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

First you should make sure that the IP connection is working.

Is NAT involved? Do you have a home connection that's reset every day and comes back with a different external IP address?

You might want to run `tcpdump -w /tmp/somefile port 22` on both sides of the connection and compare the files with wireshark afterwards.